# Solution for keeping LTS 22.04 and getting some fixes from Gnome 43

Tags: 22.04

I need to keep LTS release cause some of proprietary apps I am using that supports latest Ubuntu LTS only.
But I am having issue with default  Screen recorder not working cause of this bug that is fixed in Gnome 43.
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5585

Plus few more Gnome bugs being fixed that will not be in LTS...

I know that I can not add 43 to LTS. I can not upgrade to 22.10 cause I will lose support of app devs (plus it will probably break cause of linked libs).

How do you deal with situation like this?

Answer (score 1):

Staying with Ubuntu 22.04 means staying with Gnome 42 indeed. So you will (continue) to miss out on fixes for issues you have, and thus you will need to either work around them or live with them.

You mention a single issue: screen recording. Here, the "workaround" simply consists of finding a third party screen recording tool.

Comment: yes, that was first thing I did. But none of 3rd party screen-recorders I tried (Peek, Kooho) work, except OBS. And that looks to me like turning on truck to go visit nearby shop :D Also there are some other bugs I would like to have fixed, but I guess it is what it is. It really seems strange that you ship with OS app that does not work. It is not 3rparty app. And on top of it is LTS.